# Can I use updateDoc (firebase) inside for loop?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I need to do arrayUnion the each item of an object(props.ratings) in firebase updateDoc. I tried using for loop for code simplicity.

`props.ratings` object:

```
{
    overall: 3.5,
    food: 4,
    service: 5,
    ambience: 3,
    valueForMoney: 2.5,
  }
```

The operation I tried:

```
for(const type in props.ratings){
    updateDoc(docRef,{
      `ratings.types.${type}` : arrayUnion({
        uId:props.uId,
        val:props.ratings[type],
      }),
    }).then(()=>{}).catch(()=>{});
  }
```

The error I got: `Property assignment expected.`
Is there any way like this? or I can only manually update the doc?

Comment: You could use the spread operator in ES6 syntax. Example: `const italianRegions = ['Calabria', 'Umbria']; // ... regions: arrayUnion(...italianRegions)`.

Comment: But there, problem is it is not allowing to use variables inside filed name string